# untracked files

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, git-untracked

[image]

```
~ master ?49 ❯ git status
> warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

~ master ?49 ❯
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What does `?49` mean? Does it have to do something with Git?

Also, when I enter `git status` it lists all my files and give me this:

```
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Is this similar to https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/issues/60?

Comment: @maievS : You ask about the meaning of the characters in your prompt, but you did not post how you have defined your prompt string!

Comment: @maievS : On `git status`, `git` always lists those file in your git directory which are not put into git yet. You have to make up your mind: Either you add the files into your repo, or you put them into `.gitignore`.

Comment: This is why I don't like using `oh-my-zsh`. It provides a giant pile of customization that the user isn't necessarily aware of, making it difficult to answer questions like "Why does my shell behave like this?" (As a source of *ideas* for customization, I love `oh-my-zsh`.)

Comment: I suspect 49 refers to the number of untracked files, which `git status` (but not `zsh`)  ignores.

Answer (score 0):

`?49` in your prompt means there are 49 untracked files in the current Git repository.

From the [Powerlevel10k FAQ](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean):

> **Q: What do different symbols in Git status mean?**
>
> When using *Lean*, *Classic* or *Rainbow* style, Git status may look like this:
>
> ```
> feature:master ⇣42⇡42 *42 merge ~42 +42 !42 ?42
> ```
>
> Legend:
>
> ```
> | Symbol  | Meaning                                                           | Source                                               |
> | --------| ------------------------------------------------------------------| ---------------------------------------------------- |
> | feature | current branch; replaced with #tag or @commit if not on a branch  | git status                                           |
> | master  | remote tracking branch; only shown if different from local branch | git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} |
> | ⇣42     | this many commits behind the remote                               | git status                                           |
> | ⇡42     | this many commits ahead of the remote                             | git status                                           |
> | *42     | this many stashes                                                 | git stash list                                       |
> | merge   | repository state                                                  | git status                                           |
> | ~42     | this many merge conflicts                                         | git status                                           |
> | +42     | this many staged changes                                          | git status                                           |
> | !42     | this many unstaged changes                                        | git status                                           |
> | ?42     | this many untracked files                                         | git status                                           |
> ```
>
> See also: [How do I change the format of Git status?](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-change-the-format-of-git-status)

If you've created a Git repository at the root of your home directory to store dotfiles, you probably want to ignore untracked files in it. You can achieve this by executing the following command:

```sh
git -C ~ config status.showuntrackedfiles no
```

This will have several effects:

- The warning about permissions on `.Trash` will disappear.
- `git status` will be faster.
- `git status` won't list 49 untracked files.
- `?49` will disappear from your prompt.

You can undo the above command with the following command:

```sh
git -C ~ config --unset status.showuntrackedfiles
```